# How to implement Single Sign on using wso2

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement Single Signon for my java web application developing using spring framework, and I don't have insight into how to proceed for Single Sign On usig WSo2, Can I have advice for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use WSO2 Identity Server product for this. WSO2 Identity Server can act as a SAML2 SSO IDP. It supports for SSO profile, SSO logout profile and Basic attribute profile. If you want to achieve SSO with your web application,  first web application must be a SAML2 SSO relying party. It means that it can process SAML2 response that are received from IDP.  SAML2 java web application can be found [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/4.5.0/modules/samples/sso/SSOAgentSample/). This web application contains the java logic to process SAML2 response,  to send SAML2 request. You can go through it and understand. Also then you need to register your web application with WSO2 Identity Server as a relying party. Where you can find it in the [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Managing+Single+Sign-On)